# Conditional Select in R

Tags: r

For the sample table below, I want to select only rows where the Unique_ID is the same but Tail_No is different.

```
 My_data_table
 Unique_ID  Tail_No  
  1AA        1234 
  1AA        1234     
  1AA        4234      
  3AA        5234      
  4AA        6234      
  4AA        7234      
  6AA        1284      
  7AA        1234
```

I want my result table to look like this

```
   My_data_table
  Unique_ID  Tail_No  
   1AA        1234      
   1AA        4234           
   4AA        6234      
   4AA        7234
```

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

filter(df, Unique_ID %in% Unique_ID[duplicated(Unique_ID)]) %>% 
  distinct(Unique_ID, Tail_No)
```

Comment: But that also keeps rows that have the same `Unique_ID` *and* the same `Tail_No`. For example, if there were two rows with `1AA 1234` it would keep both whereas he/she asks for only those with the same `Unique_ID`, but different `Tail_No`.

Comment: Simple fix of using `distinct`

Answer (score 0):

The data subset you provided and your question are not that clear. Here is my best guess:

- Create the data frame:

  ```
  df <- structure(list(Unique_ID = c("1AA", "1AA", "3AA", "4AA", "4AA", "6AA", "7AA"),
                   Tail_No = c(1234, 4234, 5234, 6234, 7234, 1284, 1234)),
              class = "data.frame",
              .Names = c("Unique_ID", "Tail_No"),
              row.names = c(NA, -7L))
  ```
- We divide the problem in two steps:

  ```
  library(dplyr)
  df1 <- df %>%
     group_by(Unique_ID) %>% # Group your rows per their unique ID
     filter(n() > 1)  %>% # Keep rows that have repeated UIDs
     ungroup() # Undo grouping (not needed anymore)
  print(df1)
  ```

This is the table with repeated Unique IDs

```
  Unique_ID Tail_No
      <chr>   <dbl>
1       1AA    1234
2       1AA    4234
3       4AA    6234
4       4AA    7234
```

- Keep rows that have a unique `(UID, Tail_No)` tuple:

  ```
  df2 <- df1 %>%
     group_by(Unique_ID, Tail_No) %>%
     filter(n() == 1)  %>%
     ungroup()
  print(df2)
  ```

And that is the result:

```
  Unique_ID Tail_No
      <chr>   <dbl>
1       1AA    1234
2       1AA    4234
3       4AA    6234
4       4AA    7234
```

Maybe (your question is not clear) you want rows with a unique Tail_No that had repeated Unique_ID. If that is the case you would need to:

- Keep rows that have a unique `Tail_No`:

  ```
  df2 <- df1 %>%
     group_by(Tail_No) %>%
     filter(n() == 1)  %>%
     ungroup()
  print(df2)
  ```

And that is the result:

```
  Unique_ID Tail_No
      <chr>   <dbl>
1       1AA    1234
2       1AA    4234
3       4AA    6234
4       4AA    7234
```

Your question and dataset examples are not clear, though. Hopefully this answer is useful for you